# django has_perm always false

Tags: python, django

I have a issue using `has_perm` method of a user geted by id. should return true because i added using

> usr.user_permissions.add(p)

i refresh the user object get again by id but still returned false. even when even in the admin it appears. if someone knows something else. Here I leave part of my setings, user model and example of the code I use

```
class User(AbstractUser):

name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

def __str__(self):
```

***********************settings***********************

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_filters',
'administration',
'work',
'bank',
'providers',
'customers',
'users',
]
```

**********************code example*********************

```
url = reverse_lazy('user:list', kwargs={'id': self.kwargs['user']})
user_obj = User.objects.get(id =self.kwargs['user'])
perm = Permission.objects.get(id =self.kwargs['perm'])

if user_obj.has_perm(perm):
    print("removed")
    user_obj.user_permissions.remove(perm)
else:
    print("add")
    user_obj.user_permissions.add(perm)
success_message = "User perm changed"
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: `has_perm` expects a string, not a Permission object.

Comment: i check too using <app label>.<codename> but return false